# How to prove this type of equivalence?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that from:
$P \ \rlap\Leftarrow\Rightarrow  Q$.

It follows that: $(P \Rightarrow R)\, \rlap\Leftarrow\Rightarrow (Q \Rightarrow R)$

I don't understand where the $R$ suddenly came from? I try to use [these](http://www.cs.um.edu.mt/gordon.pace/Teaching/DiscreteMaths/Laws.pdf) rules as a reference.

Comment: You should imagine the word "*if*" somewhere: **If** $(P\implies R)$ we have $(Q\implies R)$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\begin{align} P \iff Q &\equiv  \lnot P \iff \lnot Q \\ \\ [\lnot P \iff \lnot Q]&\implies [(\lnot P \lor R)  \iff (\lnot Q \lor R)]\\ \\ & \equiv (P\rightarrow R)\iff (Q\rightarrow R)\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow thanks. I understand that!
Ah man, I need to practice this a LOT..

Comment: You're welcome! It gets easier, with practice!

Comment: I believe you mean to use implication instead of equivalence...consider $$\bigg(P \iff Q \bigg) \equiv \bigg( (P \Rightarrow R) \iff (Q \Rightarrow R)\bigg)$$
for $P$, $\lnot Q$, and $R$.

$$\bigg(\top \iff \bot \bigg) \equiv \bigg( (\top \Rightarrow \top) \iff (\bot \Rightarrow \top)\bigg)$$
$$\bot \equiv \bigg( \top \iff \top\bigg)$$
$$\bot$$

Comment: Thanks, @DanielV. I replaced equivalence with implication at the one crucial spot.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks, I'd be interested what your justification is for the implicative step.  Although we all intuitively know it is true, I'm not so sure that the logic of the linked PDF properly defends that transition.

Comment: @DanielV Right—it seems like you're just bypassing the critical step and throwing in some extra negations.

Answer (score 2):

You have linked an attachment with "some rules" but I'm expecting that you know also about *inference rules*, like $\Rightarrow$-elimination (*modus ponens*) and $\Rightarrow$-introduction [see Gordon J. Pace, [Mathematics of Structures for Computer Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A9YH45Q) (2012), page 34].

Also *transitivity* of implication [page 35] is useful :

> $(P ⇒ Q) \land (Q ⇒ R) \vdash P ⇒ R$.

Having these rules at your disposal, you can "unpack" $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ into $(P \Rightarrow Q) \land (Q \Rightarrow P)$.

Thus, by $\land$-elimination, we have :

> $P \Leftrightarrow Q \vdash P \Rightarrow Q$
>
> $P \Leftrightarrow Q \vdash Q \Rightarrow P$.

Then, from $P \Rightarrow R$ and $Q \Rightarrow P$, by transitivity you may have :

> $(Q \Rightarrow P), (P \Rightarrow R) \vdash Q \Rightarrow R$

and by $\Rightarrow$-introduction conclude with :

> $Q \Rightarrow P \vdash (P \Rightarrow R) \Rightarrow (Q \Rightarrow R)$.

In the same way, we have :

> $P \Rightarrow Q \vdash (Q \Rightarrow R) \Rightarrow (P \Rightarrow R)$.

Thus, by $⇔$-introduction [page 38] :

> > $(P \Rightarrow Q), (Q \Rightarrow P) \vdash (P \Rightarrow R) \Leftrightarrow (Q \Rightarrow R)$.

Putting all together :

> > $P \Leftrightarrow Q \vdash (P \Rightarrow R) \Leftrightarrow (Q \Rightarrow R)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more of an involved question that it seems at first glance.  Define (T1) as
$$P \Rightarrow Q \tag{T1}$$
and define (T2) as
$$(P \Rightarrow R) \iff (Q \Rightarrow R) \tag{T2}$$

First, if you are trying to prove $T_1 \equiv T_2$, you are going to have trouble because it's not true, a counter example is $P$, $\lnot Q$, and $R$.

Second, if you are trying to prove $T_1 \vdash T_2$, while a sound statement, you are still going to have trouble.  $\vdash$ roughly means "it follows from your logical rules of inference".  Look at the logical rules of inference on your linked PDF.  They are all of the form $\text{this} \equiv \text{that}$.  But since we've already established that you can't infer $T_1 \equiv T_2$ (assuming your linked PDF is sound) then no application of the rules in the PDF can give us $T_1 \vdash T_2$.

What you *can* do, if you are bound to the logic of your PDF, is to prove
$$T_1 \Rightarrow T_2 \equiv \text{true}$$

This is still a bit tricky since your PDF doesn't specify whether $\equiv$ means that replacement can be done inside an expression, or whether the rule has to applied to the whole expression.  But because there aren't any rules where $\iff$ exists not as the root function of the transform, we have to assume internal replacement is possible, otherwise a proof doesn't exist within the logic of the PDF.

I don't think there is much to learn from actually tediously figuring out which rules of inference give your equation, so I'll just point out some observations about the PDF:

- It seems to be missing a rule that $P \lor \lnot P \equiv \text{true}$, and I can't seem to figure out how to make one...
- Many of the rules of the PDF are redundant
- Working in a logic that only admits equivalences can be fun and enlightening, but is not recommended for a beginner, I strongly recommend a different reference

Comment: Thank you for the comment and advice, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

One way to see this is with the [method of analytic tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux), since you can pull $P\leftrightarrow Q$ out from $P\leftrightarrow Q\vdash ((P\to R)\leftrightarrow(Q\to R))$ and just show $\vdash (P\leftrightarrow Q)\to ((P\to R)\leftrightarrow(Q\to R))$. That boils down to showing $$(P\leftrightarrow Q)\to ((P\to R)\leftrightarrow(Q\to R))\tag{1}$$ is a tautology. You apply a series of contradiction-hunting rules to the negation of $(1)$ to get a tableau, like so

[image],

which is *closed* (i.e., each path ends in a contradiction), meaning that $(1)$ was indeed a tautology.

Can you complete the tableau? (There's a hint below.)

> It continues after the $?$ in the exact same way it does after $P\to R$, *mutatis mutandis*.

See the [*Handbook of Tableau Methods*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Handbook-Tableau-Methods-M-DAgostino/dp/0792356276) for a precise, detailed account of this approach.

I hope that helps :)

---

*NB:* [Here's the code for the diagram above.](https://www.writelatex.com/1172323kfgptk#/2802574/)

Comment: One disadvantage with this method is that it obscures which rules are being used and when; it's great for computation and for getting a feel for why theorems hold, but not for understanding the rules. So maybe this answer wasn't what you were after. I'm sorry.